# With what keys can a user leave a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, key, lost-focus

I'm trying to [determine whether or not a user left the WPF TextBox using the keyboard or the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344652/did-user-use-keyboard-or-mouse-to-leave-wpf-textbox).

If I decide to monitor the TextBox for certain keys being pressed, what are the keys for which I should watch? Put another way (hence the question title):

**Question**: With what keys can a user possibly leave a WPF TextBox?

Is it only <kbd>Tab</kbd> , or are there other keys to consider?

Comment: What about changing application focus? Does that count?

Comment: @spender: No.  The action I'm trying to take when the user leaves the field using the keyboard shouldn't fire when application focus changes.

Comment: im thinking its just Tab you need to watch out for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget about

- Shift-tab
- Arrow keys (depending on focus)
- Alt menu option key combinations
- Alt-tab
- Windows key

Comment: shift-tab for sure. Most of the rest would take focus away from the app, which wouldn't fire a losing/got focus event in the app, I don't think. I'm not sure about the arrow keys, though. In what case would the arrow keys cause the focus to change? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

tab by default. However, In windows forms (including WPF) you have full control over everything so the keystrokes/keystroke combinations that could cause a control to lose focus is virtually limitless. It would probably be fairly easy to see if anything specific could cause a specific control to lose focus, but covering all possibilities is impractical in the general case.

Also, have you considered how to handle voice recognition software that lets a user navigate a screen?

Comment: The voice recognition concern might be appropriate for someone with a wider user scope than mine.